# Spring boot : How to deal with chunks when uploading a file

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, chunks

In my Spring boot app I can upload local files to the server which works fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity uploadoFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
    SaveFile(file, headers);
}
```

However the uploaded files can be large so I decided to use a library in the front app that used chunks while uploading, each chunk with a fixed size (ex: 1MB).

Now since each chunk is sent in a separate request, the rest controller is called for each chunk, so the SaveFile will save the last chunk (override each time the saved chunk).

I need a solution where I can use the chunks and save the whole file.

Comment: > so I decided to use a library in the front app that used chunks
Which library?